# ADO Release pipeline -> How to make pipeline to restore the artifact added to it?

Tags: azure-devops, nuget-package

I have a release pipeline with an artifact added to it. Also I have below tasks, my problem is I don't know how to include that artifact while NuGet Restore such that my pipeline will run on the specified artifact.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZbXz.png)

I tried adding a powershell script to replace nuget version string in .csproj and packages.config, this solves my problem for now, but not consistent always